# Spring Boot + Vaadin deploy

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, railway

I'm trying to deploy my simple spring boot project to railway, but have error:

> va.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize
> com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener
>
> at
> com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:191)
> ~[vaadin-spring-24.1.7.jar!/:na]
>
> at
> com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213)
> ~[vaadin-spring-24.1.7.jar!/:na]
>
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
>
> used by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>
> Failed to find the following files:
>
> - ./generated/jar-resources/lit-renderer.ts
> - ./generated/jar-resources/gridConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/vaadin-time-picker/timepickerConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/contextMenuConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/vaadin-grid-flow-selection-column.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/buttonFunctions.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/dndConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/messageListConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/contextMenuTargetConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/datepickerConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/vaadin-big-decimal-field.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/comboBoxConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/selectConnector.js
> - ./generated/jar-resources/tooltip.ts

Is something wrong with my built configuration?

Second try: now i have a new error

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to find index.html. It should
> be available on the classpath w

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on how to build and run a production build?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to deploy a development mode build. Make sure you build a production mode build.

Comment: now i have new error)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to find index.html. It should be available on the classpath w

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.